# .htaccess rule conflict

Tags: .htaccess

I have following rule on my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ stat.php?domain=$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /page/404
```

and it seems like the rule is conflicting with each other.
I know that the first rule is slightly incorrect to detect a domain name.

so can any one help me what may be the proper rule to detect a domain name and rewrite the following rule from above code:

`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ stat.php?domain=$1 [L]`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to send every request through stat.php?  If so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ stat.php?domain=%{HTTP_HOST}&page=$1 [L]
```

I think the part you were looking for is `%{HTTP_HOST}`.